# Duplicating a row on successful join in mySQL

Tags: mysql

First of all, I'd like to say that I do see this is a foolish way of doing things - and that I can live without what I'm asking, however it'd be nice to see if this is possible.

Okay, imagine that I have these tables - they're not what I really have but it should still show the same problem:

```
mutex: (table, row_id)
events: (id, title, location)
files: (id, title, filesize)

groups: (id, name)
groups_to_content: (group_id, table, row_id)
```

At this current moment in time, if I want to return details about all events and files that a particular user has created, I can do that with a view that is absurdly complicated yet quick. That bit, I have no problem with.

However, the bit that I do have a problem is with groups. In the current view that I have - if a file/event hasn't been assigned to a group, then the `group_id` will be of course, NULL. If I have assigned an event to a group (via `groups_to_content`), its `group_id` will also of course, be populated:

```
+---------+----------+------------+--------------------+
|  table  |  row_id  |  group_id  |  title             |
+---------+----------+------------+--------------------+
|  event  |  1       |  NULL      |  some event        |
|  event  |  2       |  NULL      |  some event        |
|  event  |  3       |  1         |  grouped event     |
+---------+----------+------------+--------------------+
```

However, I'd like it so that it would *include* events owned by the groups that own it (multiple group ownership is possible in the system) and with `group_id` as `NULL`, as so:

```
+---------+----------+------------+--------------------+
|  table  |  row_id  |  group_id  |  title             |
+---------+----------+------------+--------------------+
|  event  |  1       |  NULL      |  some event        |
|  event  |  2       |  NULL      |  some event        |
|  event  |  3       |  NULL      |  grouped event     |
|  event  |  3       |  1         |  grouped event     |
+---------+----------+------------+--------------------+
```

Is this at all possible?

Comment: What is your end goal with this functionality (i.e. _why_ do you want to add an extra `NULL` record for events in groups)?